# Easiest way to connect Hazelcast JCache implementation to JSR107 annotations

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, hazelcast, jcache, jsr107

[Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/) is - among other things - [an implementation for JCache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/jcache.html). The [JSR-107 (JCache) specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107), along with a programmatic API also specifies annotations, so that caching can be done using CDI. [The Hazelcast Blog even gives an example](http://blog.hazelcast.com/how-jsr107-caching-annotations-are-meant-to-be-used/), but also states, that Hazelcast is not be responsible for connecting the annotations to the JCache implementation, and that this should be done by the CDI container. Standard CDI containers don't yet, but this should already be a solved problem. [There is even a reference implementation](https://github.com/jsr107/RI), but it broadly warns against being used in production environments.

Are we really stuck with either using this reference implementation code, or writing our own glue code? Is there no real, finished CDI solution for connecting the annotations to the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JCache [didn't make it into JEE7](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2613192/java/jcache-caching-standard-won-t-make-it-into-java-ee-7.html), so it's not surprising that you find some partial implementations with the label "do not use". You will have to wait for JEE8 or invent something your own ...